# iOS customize UIButton with dynamic content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a button that needs to be customized a lot, as shown in the image below:

[image]

In the image, *"2/8 Weeks" is dynamic content* so naturally I wanted to created a subclass of `UIButton` and put a label in it however `UIButton` did not allow me to do that.

By saying `UIButton` did not allow me to do that I mean: in storyboard I cannot drag a label into the button as its subview --- the label always sits on the save level as the button, not as the button's child. I tried to create an xib file for the button, but when I create a new objective class subclassed from UIButton, the "create xib file" option is grey.

As such task always has multiple solutions, my question is: what is the recommended/best way to do that?

UPDATE: I added the label as a subview of the button in code. However, the label won't be automatically dimmed when the button is pressed. I have to listen to the button event and adjust the label in order to make it work. But I don't think this is good solution so if anyone has a better solution please tell me!

Comment: Can be done with label added as subview.. What is the issue are you facing?

Comment: @iDev I updated the question ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> however UIButton did not allow me to do that.

Actually it does. 
Just make a UILabel and add as subview to your button.
example.

```
@interface MyButton()

@end

@implementation

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    UILabel *weekLabel = [UILabel new];
    weekLabel.text = @"some text here";
    weekLabel.font = someFont;
    [weekLabel sizeToFit];
    weekLabel.frame = CGRectMake(someX, someY, weekLabel.frame.size.width, weekLabel.frame.size.height);

    [self addSubview:weekLabel];
}

@end
```

and so on.

Comment: Another idea would be to create a XIB with it

Comment: I tried doing it in storyboard, but I cannot add a label as a subview  of a button in storyboard, I cannot create an xib file for a UIButton either. I don't understand why Xcode allows this in code but not in interface builder?

Comment: Yeah, XCode does not allow to change UIButton's view hierarchy via storyboards. Buy you can open your .storyboard file with textedit and do that by writing xml code :)))